# Enforcing baseline alignment for multiple overbraces in math mode

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath

What is the easiest way to vertically align overbraces in math? In the following example...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{math}
*(m, n) = (\overbrace{n - m}^\text{index}, \overbrace{\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}{\pi_{i_k}}}^\text{sum})
\end{math}

\end{document}
```

...because the second tuple element has greater vertical extent (due to the summation), the brace appears higher than the other one. I would like to have "index" and "sum" on the same baseline:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps easiest is to use `\vphantom` to make a strut the size of the larger expression

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\suma{\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}{\pi_{i_k}}}
\begin{math}
*(m, n) = (\overbrace{\vphantom{\suma}n - m}^\text{index}, \overbrace{\suma}^\text{sum})
\end{math}

\end{document}
```