# Vertically aligned \underbracket's in an equation

Tags: math-mode, equations

```
\[
\underbracket[0.5pt]{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a \\
b
\end{array}
\right)}_{v_1} \qquad
\underbracket[0.5pt]{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{array}
\right)}_{v_2}
\]
```

gives

[image]

I would like both brackets to lie on the same line, i.e., sthg like
[image]

Comment: See also [Enforcing baseline alignment for multiple overbraces in math mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101669) (possible duplicate?)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Thanks for the link. I thought about vphantom. However, I am looking for another solution that works in more complicated examples?

Comment: @user7064 It may be possible to produce a more general solution to the baseline-alignment problem, but you need to explain what you mean by more "complicated examples".

Comment: @Jubobs: I have an equation that combines several vectors and matrices (of different lengths/dimensions). Using \vphantom might be possible, but will result in awfull code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
\underbracket[0.5pt]{\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
  a \\
  b
 \end{array}
 \right)
 \vphantom{\left(\begin{array}{c}a \\b \\c\end{array}\right)}
}_{v_1}
```

EDIT: This might work

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{matrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      a \\ b
    \end{pmatrix}
    &
    \begin{pmatrix}
      a \\ b \\c 
    \end{pmatrix}
    \\[-1em]
    \underbracket[0.5pt]\qquad_{v1} 
    &
   \underbracket[0.5pt]\qquad_{v2} 
  \end{matrix}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

(anyone know how to get dvipng to not to cut off so tightly?)

Comment: @Thanks +1. Is there another solution than vphantom?

Comment: Not really. The problem is that the fences (the ()'s) are symetric about the math centerline, thus we cannot just use the [b] option for `array`

Comment: Thx, I will try and probably accept thereafter

Comment: @daleif using `[b]` with delimiters is where `delarray` comes in:-)

Answer (score 1):

Please always post complete documents showing all packages used. (I only got `mathtools` due to other answers)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{delarray,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\underbracket[0.5pt]{
\begin{array}[b]({c})
a \\
b
\end{array}
}_{v_1} \qquad
\underbracket[0.5pt]{
\begin{array}[b]({c})
a \\
b \\
c
\end{array}
}_{v_2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That was the package I had forgotten. I was messing with blockarray. Is delarray compatible with the array package and this memoir?

Comment: @daleif delarray uses array (actually delarray is a bit of array we decided not to put into the latex2e version of array) no reason why it shouldn't work with memoir